# Rails 4: When is a database connection established?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, heroku

I'm deploying a Rails 4 app on Heroku. As I'm looking over the database plans available, I don't understand what the 'connection limit' means. The 'hobby tier plans' has a connection limit of 20. The next tier has a limit of 60. Now I'm curious when a database connection is established, so that I can calculate which plan is best for me. Is there a connection for every query? Because if so, it would mean that only 20 users can use the app at the time. I quess some of these are cached, but anyway, I'm not clear on this. Thanks for your help in advance! :)

Comment: good question. Seems heroku will nickel & dime you for everything...

Comment: I found something on the rails `ConnectionPool`. http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/ConnectionPool.html It suggests that the connection limit forced by Heroku is the number of simultaneous requests the Rails app can make to the database. So if you have a limit of 20, the 21'th connection has to wait until a connection is free. This will be done automatically by the Rails ConnectionPool. I'll do some more research on this!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the rails process starts up it will grab a database connection and hold on to that connection until the process stops.

For most MRI Ruby apps you need 1 connection per process, you will most likely run unicorn on heroku with 3 workers per dyno, each worker will need 1 database connection. 
When you connect to console `heroku run console` that will use a new database connection until you logout of the console.

- https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/rails-unicorn

If you are running a threaded Ruby like jruby then each thread will need its own database connection.

Checkout "Concurrency and Database Connections in Ruby with ActiveRecord" on the heroku docs, it is has very detailed explanation:

- https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/concurrency-and-database-connections